# Как отличить реальное событие от скриптового?

Tags: javascript

Насколько я понял [event.isTrusted](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted) не имеет должной поддержки. Выходит нужно использовать что то вроде этого:

```
function handler(event) {
    if (event != 'script') {
        //...
    }
}
elem.onclick = handler;
elem.handler('script');
```

Comment: Может попробовать проанализировать стек вызовов [caller](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller)

Answer (score 0):

То что ты предложил, приятель, вообще не событие, а тупо вызов обработчика события! Чтобы инициировать событие следует использовать метод `elem.dispatchEvent(event)` а объект события можно собирать при помощи конструктора `new Event` и ничего не мешает тебе добавить в полученный объект свойство `isTrusted` или какое угодно другое своё свойство которое ты дальше проверишь в своём обработчике. А вообще то что ты тут спросил это нафиг никому не нужно.

Comment: Спасибо, братан.